# Читаю файл. В IDEA всё проходит, а на сайте даёт ошибку 404 The requested resource is not available

Tags: javascript, java

```
<form name="form1" action=" + ksGlobal.contextPath + "/main/refer/account/ajax_loadfiles_subconto enctype="multipart/form-data"   method="post" >
   <input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" id="buttonFile"/>
   <input type = "submit" value = "Загрузить файл" id="buttonSubmit"/> 
</form>
java
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax_loadfiles_subconto", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String dataLoadFilesSubconto(
   HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   @RequestParam(value = "idParam", required = false) Integer idAccountSubconto,
   @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Вы показали только форму и контроллер. А страница то сама есть? Попробуйте поместить эту форму на другую страницу и проверьте, там она будет работать или нет

Comment: Форма и контроллер срабатывают, файл читается под IDEA а как помещаю проект на сервер - файл не читает

Comment: Честно, давно работаю с IDEA, но не знал, что можно компилировать сайт и проверять чисто на ней, дадите ссылку на инструкцию или краткую информацию, как можно скомпилировать и запустить сайт через IDEA? Через Postman проверить контроллер, я еще могу понять, но форму...

Answer (score 0):

В коде

```
action=" + ksGlobal.contextPath + "/main/refer/account/ajax_loadfiles_subconto
```

заменил на

```
action=/main/refer/account/ajax_loadfiles_subconto
```

т. е убрал контекст. На локале (localhost:8080) он пустой, а на сервере в нем содержится имя приложения. и поэтому контекст не находит. Но почему так не пойму

Answer (score 0):

> как можно скомпилировать и запустить сайт через IDEA?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

> action=" ...

Здесь достаточно указать адрес вашего контроллера, который принимает данные от формы.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajax_loadfiles_subconto"....
```

то есть

```
action="/ajax_loadfiles_subconto"
```

Принцип такой:

1. на форме вы указываете вот так

```js
 <!--Информационная часть экрана-->
      <form id="auth" action="${Const.AUTHORIZATION}" method="POST">
          <!-- Объявляем форму для авторизации-->
          <table id="tableInfo">
              <tr>
                  <td id="cellTableInfoLogin"></td>
                  <td id="cellTableInfoPass"></td>
                  <td id="cellSubmit"></td>
                  <td id="forgotPassword"></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </form>
```

2. Когда форма отправляется (можно также использовать обычный html ) то запрос приходит на контроллер, который имеет адрес указанный в **action**
3. После того как запрос будет обработан, в контроллере вы указываете перенаправление на другую страницу, либо можете клиенту вернуть обратно форму с указанными ошибками.

Answer (score 0):

> action=/main/refer/account/ajax_loadfiles_subconto

action=" + ksGlobal.contextPath + "/main/refer/account/ajax_loadfiles_subconto

оба варианта не верны, нужно указать только адрес контроллера и больше ничего

```js
@WebServlet( "/users" )
public class UserAllController extends HttpServlet {
...
}
```

Если используете Spring, тогда

```js
   @Controller
public class RegistrationController {


@GetMapping("/reg")
public ModelAndView showUsersPage() {

    return new ModelAndView("/WEB-INF/pages/registration.html");
}
}
```

Когда приходит запрос, клиенту отправляется страница с формой регистрации.
Когда клиент выполнит регистрацию, происходит отправка данных на **Rest service**, после того
как данные будут обработаны, клиент перенаправляется на другую страницу.

Основная валидация у меня на стороне клиента (jQuery), данные от формы идут через ajax (в формате **JSON**) поступают на **endpoint** одного из **Rest** контроллеров (ресурс), который обрабатывает данные.
Как только данные будут успешно обработаны, сервер отправляет код 200, который на стороне клиента принимается и в этом случае там указано перенаправление на страницу по умолчанию(например пользователь успешно заполнил форму регистрации и он перенаправляется на страницу Входа в систему).

Если пользователь сделал ошибки (допустим, что валидация на стороне клиента не все проверила или не смогла) на сервере сделана дополнительная валидация. В этом случае клиенту отправляется JSON С кодом ошибки и с сообщениями об ошибке.
Этот объект можно сделать как содержащим одну строку , так и много ( строка на каждое поле формы, где замечена ошибка).
Когда Json с ошибкой придет клиенту, ajax-функция разбирает этот JSON и выводит на страницу с формой и т.д.